# Athena query after create table get no result

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

I received List, and Read permissions to the S3 bucket, as you can see I'm able to see it from my UI and the file is parquet.

[image]

Now I'm try to query it by Athena so I used this statement to create a new table :

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `test_data`.`test_funnel` (
  `request_id` string,
  `request_time_ms` timestamp,
  `request_date` timestamp,
  `request_day` timestamp,

)
PARTITIONED BY (`dt` string, `is_won` int)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.serde.ParquetHiveSerDe'
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.MapredParquetInputFormat' OUTPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.MapredParquetOutputFormat'
LOCATION 's3://data/data_a/agg_data_b/'
TBLPROPERTIES ('classification' = 'parquet');
```

When I tried to query this table I got no result, please advice

[image]

UPDATE: I ran `MSCK REPAIR TABLE` and got `Partitions not in metastore: data_v2:dt=20210828/20210831223158/is_won=1` , query the data and still get no result.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You partitioned your table. To make your meta store aware of those partitions you need to run [MSCK REPAIR TABLE](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/msck-repair-table.html). After that you should be able to see the data.

**Edit:**

It seems like the way you partitioned is not Hive compatible. You have a folder level between your partition folder levels (20210905*** etc.) which is not Key-Value based.

A workaround is adding those partitions manually in Glue, which is only possible if there are not too many. Otherwise you need to change your partitioning.

Comment: I did it but still no result, I updated my question

Comment: Updated my answer accordingly.